# Using Dust.js with Node.js Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, dust.js

Is there a way to get highlighting, intellisense and all for [Dust.js](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs) templates (*.dust*) in a node project in Visual Studio?

The projects created using *TypeScript* version of Node.js Tools for Visual Studio. It's Visual Studio 2013 SP4. Express.js is the core web provider here and bunch of other packages. Application is already working, but editing `.dust` files is not much of a pleasant thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio - Tools - Options - Text Editor - File Extensions

Go there to add .dust, and set it to HTML Editor.

Visual Studio will syntax highlight Mustache-like templates, so Dust looks mostly okay.